# preg_replace youtube iframe

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I've been trying to understand regex for years to no avail!

I have a system (let's say it's a forum for clarity) where users can post text etc and they can post youtube and soundcloud embed code. I am creating a filter to clean submitted content (as well as using htmlpurifier). Because our site is SSL I want to format the embed codes to https:// and change sizes of iframes etc. So what I want to do is catch all youtube and soundcloud iframes, turn them into a tag eg `"%youtube_embed%=dhusydg"`, run my filters which kill all iframes etc, then build the youtube/soundcloud iframe embedding according to my format.

So here's what I have ... that isn't working!

```
$string = preg_replace('/<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http\:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/(.*)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>\<\/iframe>/', '%youtube_embed%=$1', $string);
```

What that is supposed to do is find any standard youtube embed code, extract the video ID from the url, and turn it into a string which can be replaced later. However, my frustrating inability to get my head around regex is resulting in nothing happening! How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = '<iframe allowfullscreen frameborder="0" height="315"
src="youtube.com/embed/xxxx"; width="420"></iframe>
text
<iframe allowfullscreen frameborder="0" height="315" src="youtube.com/embed/xxxx"; width="420"></iframe> text';
$string = preg_replace(
'/<iframe.*?src="youtube.com\/embed\/(.*?)".*?<\/iframe>/si',
'%youtube_embed%=$1', $string);
print $string;
```

prints:

```
%youtube_embed%=xxxx
text
%youtube_embed%=xxxx text
```

I used s and i modifiers for the regexp to ignore the newlines and make search case insensitive:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Thanks but that is outputting %youtube_embed%=kA6sENoZXQY" frameborder="0 It also seems to be killing soundcloud iframe

Comment: @Ally Please, add HTML examples, that you need to process and what output to you want to get, so I could tune the code. I edited the question a little bit - frameborder must be gone now.

Comment: I've tried your edit, it fixes the last issue but now it kills anything that comes after it!

Comment: @Ally Give me the code, you are using for testing and show the correct result you want to get. I can't help you without it.

Comment: So I want it to be quite strict in matching the html. The content is being entered via ckeditor which for some reason changes the embed code when anything gets edited. So here's the HTML; YT raw <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> YT after edit: <iframe allowfullscreen frameborder="0" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxx" width="420"></iframe> Is that what you are after?

Comment: I think it might need to use the closing iframe tag as an end delimiter to ensure there is a closing tag to prevent breaking the page.

Comment: I'm probably not being very clear. It's killing all content after youtube embed because your regex is not looking to end at [code]</iframe>[/code] to end the match. I have tried [code]$clean = preg_replace('/<iframe.*?src="http\:\/\/www\.youtube.com\/embed\/(.*?)".*<\/iframe>/si','%youtube_embed%=$1',$clean);[/code] but that does not work. Also it has to be fairly strict to prevent something like [code]<iframe src="http://badsite.com" <!-- src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx" -->></iframe>[/code] or som e other malicious code.

Comment: Hi user4035, thanks for your time. I did try your updated version before you even posted it and several variations but none are working for some odd reason. I'm in agreement that it should work but it isn't. I even copied the embed code from the source of the test page and made this: $clean = preg_replace('/<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/(.*?)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen><\/iframe>/si','%youtube_embed%=$1', $clean); Even that isn't getting replaced!

Comment: ok I think there was a problem where entities were being returned instead of html some of the time. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user4035's help which put me in the right direction. The finished code is like this;

```
    $string = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxx"></iframe>';

    // immunize youtube iframe from filter
    $clean = preg_replace('/<iframe.*?src="http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/(.*)".*?\/iframe>/si','%youtube_embed%=$1',  html_entity_decode($string));
    // apply filtering here e.g removing non youtube iframes etc.

    // create youtube iframe to our own format e.g add class, convert to ssl and change player size etc
    $clean = preg_replace('/%youtube_embed%=(.*)/si','<iframe class="youtube" width="300" height="250" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://youtube.com/embed/$1"></iframe>',  $clean);
    echo $clean;
```

Note: the "?" in the wildcard `(.*?)` was breaking everything so I changed to `(.*)`.

EDIT
This still doesn't work. It's breaking html and blocking content that comes after the replacement.